# i have home work about script C and create IF Else Statement

Tags: algorithm, if-statement

I have a problem like this

A Taxi company has regulations regarding the rates charged to passengers as follows:
For the first Kilometer = $ 5
For the second and next Kilometer = $ 3
Input: Distance traveled
Output: Amount of payment

how to create a C script for an IF-ELSE Statement

please help me

Comment: What have you managed to do so far ? Can you show a piece of code, or even of pseudo-code, so we can know what is blocking you ?

Comment: I only got the problem, I got the problem from my school

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that calculates the price of the taxi (you probably saw that the formula to calculate it is `5 + 3*(nb_km-1)` if nb_km is stricly positive.
So you have 3 cases to distinguish:

- If nb_km is negative, you must return an error
- If it is equal to 0, you must return 0
- If it is strictly positive, you must return `5 + 3*(nb_km-1)`

Which gives this little piece of code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIRST_KM_PRICE 5
#define NEXT_KM_PRICE 3


int main() {
    int nb_km, price;              // declare an integer variable called nb_km, and one called price
    printf("enter the number of kilometers\n");
    scanf("%d", &nb_km);  // get a number for the standart input (the console), and store it in nb_km
    if (nb_km < 0) {
        printf("Error, must be a positive number of kilometers.\nExiting ...");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        if(nb_km == 0) {
            price = 0;
        } else {
            price = FIRST_KM_PRICE + (nb_km - 1) * NEXT_KM_PRICE;  // we calculate the price
        }
        printf("Price is %d dollars.\n", price);
    }
    return 0;
}
```